# How to add notes/tags to specific times while watching a video?

Tags: video-editor

I have a large archive of video that I want to catalog, so that I can go back and find clips about certain topics. So far, I've done a couple videos by playing them 1.5x and writing the time code and making a note about the topic... on paper. Then, I transfer everything into a spreadsheet. It's certainly effective, but relatively inefficient.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to create a list of tags that I can choose as I'm watching the video. Alternately, the ability to type a quick note that's tied to a particular time signature would also be good. If I have to pause the video to do it, that's a no-go. I'm thinking of something a lot like SoundCloud's feature where you can make a comment while you're listening to something.

Is there any way to do something like this in Adobe Premier, AfterEffects, or some other tool?

Comment: Is this a thing many people would want? If you don't find such a tool, comment here. I could write something fairly easily to do that.

Comment: It seems like it'd be easiest to do with Blender, partly because the other thing that I'd like to do is export all those tags and timestamps directly to a CSV or spreadsheet.

Comment: Have you tried [Adobe Prelude](https://www.adobe.com/products/prelude.html)? It is designed for shot logging prior to editing and may meet your needs. You may also find transcription software that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems possible in Adobe Premiere Pro (CS6 at least).
From your question I understand you want to do three things, I will treat every one of them separately. The steps can be used to achieve your goal.

First, open a new project in Premiere Pro (PP) and import the media you want to add comments to.
Additionally, I found the `Metalogging` window lay-out convenient for this task (`Windows` -> `Workspace` -> `Metalogging` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>), but you might find another lay-out fit your needs better.

#### 1. Play video at 1.5x speed

Double click the video you want to play, it will open in the `Source` panel.
Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to play the video and use the <kbd>L</kbd> key to increase the playback rate and the <kbd>J</kbd> decreases it (credits to [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/8485/2178)).

#### 2. Create a list of tags during playback

While the video plays hit the <kbd>M</kbd> key to create a `Marker` at the timecode currently shown in the `Source` panel (markers pointed out):

[image: source markers]

Make sure the `Source` panel is in focus (i.e. has a yellow line around the panel):
[image: panel in focus]

#### 3. Add comments to the tags without pausing the video

Make sure the `Markers` panel (`Window` -> `Markers`) and the `Source` panel is visible (`Window` -> `Source`).
When you add markers during playback, these will show up in this panel with a comment field:

[image: comments]

While the video plays, you can add markers in the `Source` panel and then add comments to these markers in the `Markers` panel. The video is not paused.

In your comment you mention you would like to export the markers to a file. Unfortunately I did not find a straightforward way to do this in CS6, however, PP Creative Cloud does have this option according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YlcNam09dJw).
The option can be found in `File` -> `Export` -> `Markers` and allows you to export an HTML file of your timestamped markers, including comments and a screenshot of the video at that time.

Comment: Excellent! This is pretty much exactly what I need!